# Cant load https://www.cognitoforms.com/login in Chrome and Edge

Tags: cognito-forms

Both  browser cant load! https://www.cognitoforms.com/login
just blank! Its pretty critical atm.. help!!!!

Google Chrome is up to date
Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Microsoft Edge is up to date.
Version 85.0.564.41 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: I'm flagging this question to be closed because the issue has been fixed on the server side, thus rendering the issue moot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no present or future benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to their SSL certificates already expired (on August 29, 2020), and thus modern browsers reject to load the resources (particularly for `static.cognitoforms.com` domain) that the page needs to work for being unsecured.

The real fix has to be done from the Cognito Forms' side to renew the SSL certificates (which is out-of-scope for end-users).

The workaround is to allow the browser to load them (tested on Chrome):

1. Open one of the resources under `static.cognitoforms.com` domain (e.g. https://static.cognitoforms.com/app/npm.core-js.d28959b695025102af27.js)
2. Chrome will show "Your connection is not private" warning
3. Click the "Advanced" button on the bottom
4. Click the "Proceed to static.cognitoforms.com (unsafe)" link
5. Reload the [login](https://www.cognitoforms.com/login) page

***Note that browsing HTTPS websites with invalid SSL certificates in general is insecure since the connection is not actually secured. Use with extreme caution!***